# Excel crash on large range copying

Tags: excel, com, ms-office, office-interop, vba

I have developed an Excel COM addin, which goes through multiple `XLSM`files (stages), generates one from another (using macro enabled templates), copies some data, and at the end it creates a PDF report.
I've recently introduced a function that with 2 workbooks open, copies a pretty large range (A1:X500) from Workbook1 to Workbook2.

```
//Copy values from W1 to W2
Excel.Worksheet WS_Out = W1.Worksheets["Out"]; 
Excel.Worksheet WS_In = W2.Worksheets["In"];
WS_In.Range["A1:X517"].Value = WS_Out.Range["A1:X517"].Value;
```

This code works sometimes. But recently it started to crash Excel without any possibility to catch the error.

It's a hard error, and makes the whole system unstable. If it doesn't fail at the copy part, then it fails on the next workbook, when I try to programmatically read a cell...

Any info on what I could be doing wrong?

I revised the previous stages and made sure that I release any worksheet or workbook reference I might've made (by using the `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` function)

Comment: 1) Which version of Excel? Historically, some versions have had bugs when reading/writing large ranges. 2) Try using `Value2` instead of `Value`. 3) Try a smaller range, and increase/decrease the size until you can figure out at what size or at which cell it starts to fail. Is there anything special about the data right around the failure point?

Comment: Hi! It happens with both Excel 2013 and 2016. Why should I use Value2? Is there a certain reason for it? I tried with smaller ranges and it crashes then as well... it happens really randomly, and only if I go through multiple excel files from start to finish. Imagine that the process has 3 stages, so 3 excel files are being generated from one another and values are copied. It only crashes this way. If I just start up excel and open the last stage (a previous attempt), it will go ahead without any problems. This left me thinking, that it could be memory related issue.

Comment: The data that i'm copying has formulas in it, but i'm not interested in that, i just want the plain values. The code snippet that I wrote above does that.

Comment: See [this](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/) for Text vs. Value vs. Value2.

Comment: Maybe your code that releases objects is what causes a crash when other addins can nolonger affect them? That would explain why you can't catch the error in your own code.